# The list of Binyamin's cities

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, eretz-yisrael, geography, joshua--book-of

When [*Y'hoshua* 15:21–62](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Joshua.15.21-62?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) lists the cities of *Y'huda*, it does so by area/topography. [*M'tzudas David* to 15:37](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Joshua.15.37?lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20David&lang2=en) says that "everywhere it counts some separately and others separately", it does so by area or topography. I assume he's referring (at least) to [18:21–28](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Joshua.18.21-28?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), where the list of *Binyamin*'s cities is divided into two but not explicitly according to any rule. Is my assumption right? If not (and even if so), is there any (further) explanation for the division in chapter 18? (Sources, please, if possible.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To judge by Tevuos Haaretz's identifications of these cities (Hebrew text [here](http://www.tevuot.org/aretz/3e.html), English translation [here](http://www.jewish-history.com/palestine/cities_of_benjamin.html)), it looks like the division is between the eastern and western areas of the territory. This also seems to be borne out by the map on [this page at Wikiyeshiva](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%98_%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F), and at the bottom of the page they say so explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! To be sure, _T'vuos Haaretz_ doesn't deal with many of them, but, as you say, those he does comment on seem to fit that pattern. Thanks much for looking up these resources, neither of which I'd heard of (online).